# How to succinctly map over a plane with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have written code to plot the average squared error of a linear function over a given dataset, to visualise progress during a gradient descent training for the optimum regression line.

The relevant bits are these:

```
def compute_error(f, X, Y):
    e = lambda x, y : (y - f(x))**2
    return sum(e(x, y) for (x, y) in zip(X, Y))/len(X)

mn, bn, density = abs(target_slope)*1.5, abs(target_intercept)*1.5, 20

M, B = map(list, zip(*[(m, b) for m in np.linspace(-mn, +mn, density)
             for b in  np.linspace(-bn, +bn, density)]))
E = [compute_error(lambda x : m*x+b, X, Y) for m, b in zip(M,B)]
```

This works, but is very messy. I suspect there might be a very succinct way to pull off the same thing with numpy. So far I have gotten this:

```
M, B = map(np.ndarray.flatten, np.mgrid[-mn:+mn:1/density, -bn:+bn:1/density])
```

I still don't know how to improve the instantiation of `E`, and for some reason right now it is a lot slower than the messy version.

So, what would be a good way to map over a plane like `M`X`B` with numpy?

---

If you want to run above code you can build `X` and `Y` like so:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import normal

target_slope = 3
target_intercept = 15

def generate_random_data(slope=1, minx=0, maxx=100, n=200, intercept=0):
    f = lambda x : normal(slope*x, maxx/5)+intercept
    X = np.linspace(minx, maxx, n)
    Y = [f(x) for x in X]
    return X, Y

X, Y = generate_random_data(slope=target_slope, intercept=target_intercept)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def compute_error(f, X, Y):
    return np.mean( (Y - f(X))**2 )

MB = np.mgrid[-mn:+mn:2*mn/density, -bn:+bn:2*bn/density]
MB = MB.reshape((2, -1)).T

E = [compute_error(lambda x : m*x+b, X, Y) for m, b in MB]
```

It is possible to write a full numpy solution:

```
Y = np.array(Y)

M, B = np.mgrid[-mn:+mn:2*mn/density, -bn:+bn:2*bn/density]

mx = M.reshape((-1,1))*X
b = B.reshape((-1,1))*np.ones_like(X)

E = np.mean( (mx+b - Y)**2, axis=1 )
```

It may also be possible to write a solution without using the need to flatten the arrays and obtain the error as a 2D array...

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully follow what you're trying to achieve here.  However, this may help get you started with a numpy solution:

```
X, Y = generate_random_data(slope=target_slope, intercept=target_intercept, n=180)
M, B = np.mgrid[-mn:+mn:1/density, -bn:+bn:1/density]
f = M.T*X + B.T
error = np.sum((f-Y)**2)
```

Note I've had to alter the default number of X,Y values

Comment: Ah, yes... but what is the transpose for?

Comment: The two transposes were used to keep the results consistent with the question.

Comment: in What way? `M+B` is the matrix of all possible sums of `b in B` and `m in M`, right? In the same vein `M*X` is the matrix of all possible products of `m in M` and `x in X`. So then `M*X + B` already is all possible values the function `m*x + b` can take on over the plane "M cross B", right?

Comment: You are correct to a point, but this is where I'm finding it difficult to follow what you're trying to achieve.  I transposed M and B to make them fit the shapes of your given X and Y.  I haven't attempted to rewrite these.